# How can I track calls/stack onthe UI thread?

Tags: c#, user-interface

I have a hefty little Winforms app written in C#. For a moment, lets assume that the box running my app has a large number of cores, so that for me, the most precious resource in the app is the use of the UI thread. In light of that, I'd like to be able to track, for performance tuning purposes, all of the calls that are being made on the UI thread. I'd like to make sure I'm not accidentally doing work on the UI thread that could be easily moved to a background thread.

My best guess so far would be using the Process Explorer and/or Process Monitor from the Microsoft SysInternals group.

Comment: I'm not sure how to give a proper answer to this but with tools like [ANTS Performance Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/) you can track the calls on each thread individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Year(s) ago I used [Managed Spy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163617.aspx) with success.

Have a look on it.

Comment: Looks like a very useful tool.

Comment: @Justin strongly recommend, good product. If it will not fit your current needs, definitely add it to your personal toolbox for future .NET applications.